# Expo eas build apk cannot install on my devices; apk was crashing but works on expo go

Tags: react-native

Here is my `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
"@arismun/format-rupiah": "^3.0.0",

"@popperjs/core": "2.11.6",

"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.11",

"@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "6.5.2",

"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",

"@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",

"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",

"@rneui/base": "^4.0.0-rc.7",

"@rneui/themed": "^4.0.0-rc.7",

"@types/react-native": "0.70.6",

"axios": "^1.3.4",

"bootstrap": "^5.2.3",

"expo": "\~47.0.12",

"expo-modules-autolinking": "1.0.0",
"expo-navigation-bar": "\~2.0.1",
"expo-splash-screen": "\~0.17.5",
"expo-status-bar": "\~1.4.2",
"expo-system-ui": "\~2.0.1",
"express-generator": "^4.16.1",
"native-base": "^3.4.26",
"npm": "^9.6.0",
"react": "18.1.0",
"react-bootstrap": "^2.7.2",
"react-bootstrap-table": "^4.3.1",
"react-dom": "18.1.0",
"react-hook-form": "^7.43.5",
"react-html-table-to-excel": "^2.0.0",
"react-native": "0.70.5",
"react-native-chart-kit": "^6.12.0",
"react-native-date-picker": "^4.2.9",
"react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
"react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.4.6",
"react-native-element-dropdown": "^2.7.1",
"react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
"react-native-ionicons": "^4.6.5",
"react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^3.0.1",
"react-native-masked-text": "^1.13.0",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "4.4.1",
"react-native-screens": "\~3.18.0",
"react-native-select-dropdown": "^3.3.0",
"react-native-svg": "13.4.0",
"react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
"react-native-table-component": "sturmenta/react-native-table-component#e1582aaba92b7e070c31c98b116eea9c23e17f6d",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
"react-native-vertical-distribution": "^1.0.2",
"react-to-print": "^2.14.12",
"sql": "^0.78.0",
"xlsx": "^0.18.5"
},
```

Here is my `eas.json`:

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 3.8.0",
    "requireCommit" : true
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m-medium"
      }
    },
    "preview": {
      "android" : {
        "buildType": "apk"
      },
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m-medium"
      }
    },
    "production": {
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m-medium"
      }
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: show the error message, are you sure all package installation already follow the guideline? I have similar issue before, I have to do minimal built that running well on production, then start add one by one, package or screen to test which package is causing this issue.

Comment: No errors. I guess, it's related to the api I'm using. But I'm sure it's working properly.

Comment: api shouldn't be issue, it's only for retrieving the data, did you put try catch error on the code that have possibility causing problem

Comment: I checked again, and it turned out that everything was according to the rules, the application was also running. however, there is a new problem, the application that I made cannot be run on several devices, is this a weakness of the React Native Expo or what? can you help me?